# how to bind to sqldate?

Tags: grails, grails3

I have a simple setup.

```
import java.sql.Date as SqlDate

class Book {

    String name
    SqlDate publishedDate

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

In application.yml

```
grails:

    databinding:
        dateFormats:
            - 'dd/MM/yyyy'
```

Book Controller save method

```
def save(){

    def book = new Book()

    bindData(book, params)


    book.save()

    render "done"

}
```

Create page

```
<g:form action="save">

    <g:textField name="name"></g:textField>
    <g:textField name="publishedDate"></g:textField>
    <g:submitButton name="Submit"></g:submitButton>

</g:form>
```

When i use normal java date then the date binding works but when i use the sql.Date then bindData() doesnt seem to bind the date. Does bindData not work on sql.Date? Thanks for help!

Comment: What happens? do you get an error?

Comment: it doesnt bind the date. I checked it using debugger and stopping right after bindData()

Comment: So the book isn't persisted at all? can you check the errors on book after the attempted bind e.g. `println book.errors`, or maybe try just creating a book with the 2 values in the constructor then `book.validate()` then `println book.errors`